# Как добавить монеты в обмен на просмотр видео?

Tags: unity3d

Извините за глупый вопрос, но какой уж есть)

Дано: работающая реклама + score
проблема: как зачислить игроку монеты за действие, если unity пишет object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Как грамотно добавить значение игроку ?

```js
 private void HandleShowResult (ShowResult result)
 {
  switch (result)
  {
  case ShowResult.Finished:
   Debug.Log ("Video completed. Offer a reward to the player.");
   break;
  case ShowResult.Skipped:
   player.GetComponent<InventoryC>().cash = 10000;
   break;
  case ShowResult.Failed:
   Debug.LogError ("Video failed to show.");
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Что получает result?

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object - ничего

Comment: result должен быть 
int  cash = 1000

Comment: Судя по коду, result типа ShowResult (enum).

Comment: А так вопрос для меня из разряда "сколько стоит картошка если козырь бубна?" Куда вы пытаетесь слать значение, что значит "игрок" в вашем контексте. Задавая вопрос представляйте, пожалуйста, что мы ничего не знаем о вашей системе и можем отталкиваться только от вашего текста.

Comment: Да, я вижу, что в одном случае вы присвоили player.GetComponent<InventoryC>().cash = 10000; Ошибку выдает на эту строчку? Если именно в этом проблема - посмотрите, где у вас присвоение "игроку". Есть ли у него компонента типа InventoryC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На какой именно строке у вас падает ошибка? 
На строке со switch (result)? 
или на строке player.GetComponent().cash = 10000;?

Если на первой - то у вас явная проблема с вызовом этого метода. Он точно подписан именно на событие из sdk рекламной площадки? SKD площадок не может выдать такой результат.

Если второй - то у вас чего-то не существует. Либо поле player равно null, либо на объекте player отсутствует компонент InventoryC.